# how to send a value from a HTML dropdown box to a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to JQuery and don't have much experience with javascript at all, and after hours of trying to figure this out i give up. I know how to do it in PHP, but there's something I'm missing when I try it in JQuery.

I have a html-file that generates a dorpdown box that looks something like tihs:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
  <select id="countiesList" name="counties">
    <option value="all" selected="selected">All Counties</option>
    <option value="county1">County 1</option>
    <option value="county2">County 2</option>
    ...
  </select>
</from>
```

1. How do I get the selected value from the dropdownbox in to a JQuery function?
   Do I have to refer to the function I want to use in the form?
2. Should I have a submit button? (I'd prefer not to)

--edited--
My point is that I want to find out which of the options the user selects, so that I can use it in another function.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by "confirm" button, but you should have some sort of "submit" button. also - are you sure you want to be using `method="GET"` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to submit it immediately on change.  In that case use the [`change` event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) like this:

```
$(function() { //run when the DOM is ready
  $("#countriesList").change(function() { //this runs when the selection changes
    $.post("myPage.php", { country: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
      //use data here
    });
  });
});
```

What this does is when your selection changes, we post to `"myPage.php"` which gets a POST variable of `country`, which will be the **value** you picked (`all`, `country`, etc).  Just get this from `$_POST["country"]` and render your response...which will be `data` in the above [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) callback.  You can then do whatever you want with that response, for example if it's another `<select>` with state, you could append that to somewhere, for example:

```
$("#nextDropDownContainer").html(data);
```